# iOS 7+ Is it possible for an application to send data via network while app is inactive?

Tags: ios, rest, http, background, geolocation

iOS 7+, 8 (last one not released yet, however targeting on it).
The app.
As a user I start the app and switch to other apps (mail, safari, etc.), leaving the app running but not a foreground one.
The app establishes HTTP connection to server via Internet and starts periodically sending GPS location data to the server (with some interval).

Is it possible while the app is not on the foreground? I mean is it possible to get geolocation data and periodically send it from the app to the server via HTTP POST while using other apps?

If the answer is "YES", please help me with references. I will investigate it further.

Comment: You can keep the app pulling GPS in the background by adding it to the pList. There are a certain number of properties that you can flag an app so that it can be retained in the background (another example is a music app). Your problem is hard because you need to turn off the GPS in between HTTP calls so you don't drain battery. This means you need to juggle keeping the app alive while the GPS is off.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, and the method you want to research is performFetchWithCompletionHandler:

> Implement this method if your app supports the fetch background mode.
>   When an opportunity arises to download data, the system calls this
>   method to give your app a chance to download any data it needs. Your
>   implementation of this method should download the data, prepare that
>   data for use, and call the block in the completionHandler parameter.
>
> When this method is called, your app has up to 30 seconds of
>   wall-clock time to perform the download operation and call the
>   specified completion handler block. In practice, your app should call
>   the completion handler block as soon as possible after downloading the
>   needed data. If you do not call the completion handler in time, your
>   app is terminated. More importantly, the system uses the elapsed time
>   to calculate power usage and data costs for your app’s background
>   downloads. If your app takes a long time to call the completion
>   handler, it may be given fewer future opportunities to fetch data in
>   the future. For more information about supporting background fetch
>   operations, see “App States and Multitasking” in iOS App Programming
>   Guide.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiapplicationdelegate_protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application:performFetchWithCompletionHandler:

Answer (score 0):

Just as Mike mentioned, you should look into background fetch. For more details, checkout this [objc.io post](http://www.objc.io/issue-5/multitasking.html).

The information you need should be in the **Background Fetch** section.